# Spring Component Scan the classes from a jar?

Tags: java, spring

Can we generate classes with Spring Bean annotation as jar file?
How to inject another Spring Bean from the class of that jar?
Can you provide the possible way? When I get as below it does not work?

In Jar File

```
    package org.java.support;

    @Service("CommonService")
    public class CommonService {
    }
```

In project

```
    package com.java.test.app;

    @Service(value = "OtherService")
    public class OtherService {
        @Resource(name = "CommonService")
        private CommonService service;
    }
```

In configuraiton

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.java.test.app, org.java.support">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

I get the following error;

```
13:32:12,331 DEBUG [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [or
g.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@32dcb03b]
13:32:12,331 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'CommonService' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
    at org.ace.java.support.delete.Test.main(Test.java:18)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand your question

Comment: This should work. Are you sure the "other" jar is included as dependency?

Comment: Did you see if Spring logs the beans "CommonService" and "OtherService" when creating the application context? Also, does "MyService" actually exist?

Comment: @genomie I am really sorry for my question, I update it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are generating your Jar from Eclipse, on the export dialog, make sure that "Add directory entries" check box (under options) is checked.

Answer (score 1):

well You are almost there :)

you will need to use include filters to add the jar to your spring context. But I think using two component scan lines should work too.

Example:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*Stub.*Repository"/>
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning